# Subscription tax not showing up as line item in PDF invoice with Laravel Cashier

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-cashier

When creating new subscriptions for users, I now include a `tax_percent` every time a new one is created. The charge amount is right and everything looks good on the Stripe end. However, when downloading the PDF of the invoice through Laravel Cashier, the GST is not showing up as a line item.

I'm looking at the `receipt.blade.php` file and there is no indication that it is even currently doing this. The only thing I see where it might possibly be able to display the tax is here:

```
<!-- Display The Invoice Items -->
@foreach ($invoice->invoiceItems() as $item)
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">{{ $item->description }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->dollars() }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

However, the `$invoice->invoiceItems()` array seems to be empty. Any ideas as to why would be much appreciated.